# Remove elements from a list with a mask

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose we have a list `{a, b, c}` and a mask `{1, 0, 1}` (or `{True, False, True}`). And we want to apply this mask to a list -- we want to keep elements that correspond to `1` or `True` in the mask and to remove elements that correspond to `0` or `False`.

I found only `Select` and `Cases` functions, but they seem to work only with patterns and functional criterion.

So what will be the good solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
Pick[{a, b, c}, {True, False, True}]
(*{a,c}*)
```

or

```
Pick[{a, b, c}, {1,0,1},1]
```